# What is the proper format to substitute ConnectionString variable in release pipeline?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, connection-string

I am using following connection string in my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <connectionString>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="__DefaultConnection__" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionString>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="__ClientValidationEnabled__" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

And in IIS Web Deploy release pipeline I am using XML Variable Substitution, by defining a variable with the key name `DefaultConnection` and `value` as `Server=127.0.0.1;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

The variable in `appsettings` gets changed on the server-side but not for the `connectionString`, Is it the correct way of declaring connection string. I am doing this for only test purposes, and do not have valid connections setup. Also in Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution-example), the format is quite different. Can anyone help me, in this case, how can I use this only for test purposes, keeping in mind the IIS server doesn't go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in the Microsoft documentation, the connection string will have to be of the same format, as you have used in the variable value like this

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True
```

Make these changes in your config file:

```
  <connectionString>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=local;Database=undefined;Trusted_Connection=False
" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionString>
```

Now run your pipelines and you should be able to see changes in `web.config` on server side.